# Parser tags for OpenNLP

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, opennlp, pos-tagger

Is there any documentation about the meaning of parser tags in OpenNLP? I know that the POS tag types follows the TreeBank convention, but unfortunately I haven't found any information about the parser tags, such as "SBAR", etc.

Does this documentation exist somewhere or I have to figure it out myself?

Comment: see here: http://blog.dpdearing.com/2011/12/opennlp-part-of-speech-pos-tags-penn-english-treebank/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Penn Treebank Tagset](http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html) and the [treebank annotation guidelines](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/treebank/doc/manual/root.ps.gz)

Comment: Thanks for the Penn Treebank Tagset link!